# Take average of multiple columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I have a pandas dataframe with 4 columns, which is how a piece of equipment is exporting data into a csv. My current code takes the csv, imports it into a dataframe, adds headers to the columns, and then runs some code on it to transform it how we need it. This is the main pieces of the code:

```
def data_an(info):
    data = pd.read_csv(info, usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3], names=["a", "b", "c", "d"])
    data = data.replace(0, np.NaN)
    return(data.mean(), data.count())

print(data_an('output.csv'))
```

and this is what it will output:

```
a    19.381846
b    18.515209
c    18.401317
d    18.849287
dtype: float64, a    10675
b    11126
c     6866
d     5496
dtype: int64
```

I was wondering how i would be able to take the average of a, b, c, and d all at the same time, so sum up the values in all 4 columns, and then take the average of all 4 columns.

Comment: what is your expected output

Answer (score 0):

## Using pandas

- If you want to take the mean of each row excluding `NaN`s, `data.mean(axis=1, skipna=True)` will work.
- If you want the mean of each column, use `data.mean(axis=0, skipna=True)` or `data.describe()`.
- If you want the mean of all entries, use `data.mean().mean()` to take the mean of all columns then all rows (equivalent to mean of all entries if there are the same number of `NaN`s in each column).

## Using numpy

You can also convert your data to a numpy array with eg `data.to_numpy(np.float64)` (which will raise an error if your data isn't numeric) and use regular numpy operations.  `np.nanmean(data.to_numpy(np.float64))` will give a correct result even if the columns of your data have different numbers of `NaN` entries.

### Example

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2, 3]})

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3

In [5]: df.to_numpy(np.float64)
Out[5]:
array([[1., 1.],
       [2., 2.],
       [3., 3.]])

In [6]: df.to_numpy(np.float64).mean(axis=1)
Out[6]: array([1., 2., 3.])

In [7]: df.to_numpy(np.float64).mean(axis=0)
Out[7]: array([2., 2.])

In [8]: df.to_numpy(np.float64).mean()
Out[8]: 2.0
```

Comment: I do like `data.describe()` but it still does it individually for each column. My post may not describe it as well as it should, but i am looking to take the average, or possibly the entire description of all 4 columns

Comment: what about adding another column which is the mean of [a,b,c,d] and then taking the mean of that? 
df['mean']=(df['a']+df['b']+df['c']+df['d'])/4

Comment: @ZachMelendez I misunderstood your question, thanks for the clarification. I've updated my answer